# Typerror while accessing parent class data members

Tags: python

I am trying to create a queue using two stacks and below is my code :-

```
class Stack1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Stack1, self).__init__()
        self.stack1 = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.stack1.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        self.popped_value = self.stack1.pop()       
        print("popped_value parent", self.popped_value)
        return self.popped_value
    def peek(self):
        try:
            return self.stack1[len(stack1)-1]
        except:
            print("Cannot peek into stack 1")
    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self.stack1) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def display(self):
        print(self.stack1)

class Stack2(Stack1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Stack2).__init__()
        self.stack2 = []        

    def push(self, popped):
        self.popped = popped
        return self.stack2.append(self.popped)
    def pop(self):
        return self.stack2.pop()
    def peek(self):
        try:
            return self.stack2[len(stack2)-1]
        except:
            print("Cannot peek into stack 2")
    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self.stack2) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def display(self):
        print(self.stack2)
class DoubleStackQueue(Stack2):     
    def __init__(self):
        super(DoubleStackQueue, self).__init__()
        pass    
    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.item = item
        super(DoubleStackQueue, self).push(self.item)       
        Stack1.push(self.item)

dsq = DoubleStackQueue()
dsq.enqueue(2)
```

Here, I am trying to push an item to stack1 by accessing the push() method of class Stack1. However, I am getting the below error :-

```
E:\>python dsq.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dsq.py", line 78, in <module>
    dsq.enqueue(2)
  File "dsq.py", line 75, in enqueue
    Stack1.push(self.item)
TypeError: push() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

Could you please help me out ?

Comment: You say `Stack1.push(self.item)`, but `Stack1` is a class, not an instance.  You need an instance of the class so that `.push()` will get the `self` argument.

Answer (score 1):

When you call an *instance method* directly from the class, as you are doing by calling `Stack1.push`, you need to explicitly provide the `self` parameter:

```
Stack1.push(self, self.item)
```

In your call `Stack1.push(self.item)` the `self.item` is passed as the `self` parameter and the interpreter raises an error because it is missing the other required positional argument `item`.

Alternatively use `super`:

```
super(Stack2, self).push(self.item)
```

---

This said:

- I believe your code is quite messy. I'm pretty sure `Stack2.push` method should be responsible for calling `Stack1.push`, so that `DoubleEndedQueue` need not perform a double call.
- You can replace `super(DoubleEndedQueue, self).push(self.item)` with just `self.push.item`... since `DoubleEndedQueue` doesn't define a `push` method the superclass `Stack2` will be checked automatically.